Unity - Renaming a folder to "Samples~" deletes the folder
When I rename my "demos" folder to "Samples~" in order to make it appear on the PackageManager window samples tab, it makes it disappear, not only hide into Unity, the files are literally gone, even in the Os file explorer, and github desktop confirm that these files are deleted.
How am I supposed to make a proper samples folder?
Ps: I initially posted this on that topic Creating a Unity package's folder "Samples~" hides it , but my post was deleted because apparently asking for another question, even if tiedly related tho.

What do you mean you "posted this on that topic"? Did you post an answer to the question with a new question?

It does not delete the folder.
It is not imported anymore and will not appear in Unity assets. Actually happens for just anything ending with ~ (see Special Folder Names -> Hidden Assets)
This is intended because for packages you are supposed to import the samples on demand via the Package Manager.
I can't reproduce this disappearing from any OS Explorer I used before - but maybe yours has some weird settings to do so .. or you have some .gitignore rule to ignore it so it is just tracked as deleted.
In general in order to be able to install samples from the Package Manager they also need to be listed in the package.json manifest under samples (see Package Manifest and Creating Samples for a Package).
Afaik this won't work with embedded and local packages though, only those you actually install via Package Manager or from a git link (might be wrong on that one though)

A hack I personally use when developing on a package is creating a symlink (you'll find many tools online to do.that) from the Samples~ into Assets/Samples in my development project. That way you can freely edit any content and check compatibility just as part of a Unity project while the package itself still works as expected and has the content actually listed in its Samples~ folder.

Now I just noted that exactly this I already explained in the post you linked

yeah I linked the post to give context and history on that, I know it's not supposed to delete, just hide, but that's what happened to me, can't say why, the folder was gone..
Anyway, on a fresh new project the vanish issue is not reproducing, so I guess it was just a bug.
Regarding the symlink approach it looks good but I choosed to use the Github Action approach described on this wonderful tutorial https://medium.com/openupm/how-to-maintain-upm-package-part-1-7b4daf88d4c4
Thanks for answer
